# Scrapy splash connection refused on localhost:8050

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have installed scrapy-splash as per official docs in windows 8.1 but when I visit http://localhost:8050/, I am getting connection refused error

Run:
`docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash`

here is a docker cmd log:

```
2019-08-14 02:09:17+0000 [-] Log opened.
2019-08-14 02:09:17.882305 [-] Splash version: 3.3.1
2019-08-14 02:09:17.886323 [-] Qt 5.9.1, PyQt 5.9.2, WebKit 602.1, sip 4.19.4, Twisted 18.9.0, Lua 5.2
2019-08-14 02:09:17.888056 [-] Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2019-08-14 02:09:17.891068 [-] Open files limit: 1048576
2019-08-14 02:09:17.892217 [-] Can't bump open files limit
2019-08-14 02:09:18.008683 [-] Xvfb is started: ['Xvfb', ':504837395', '-screen', '0', '1024x768x24', '-nolisten', 'tcp']
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
2019-08-14 02:09:18.572706 [-] proxy profiles support is enabled, proxy profiles path: /etc/splash/proxy-profiles
2019-08-14 02:09:18.575273 [-] memory cache: enabled, private mode: enabled, js cross-domain access: disabled
2019-08-14 02:09:19.282557 [-] verbosity=1, slots=20, argument_cache_max_entries=500, max-timeout=90.0
2019-08-14 02:09:19.291644 [-] Web UI: enabled, Lua: enabled (sandbox: enabled)
2019-08-14 02:09:19.297131 [-] Site starting on 8050
2019-08-14 02:09:19.299929 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site object at 0x7fe5346cbcc0>
2019-08-14 02:09:19.302557 [-] Server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8050
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the port because it is hard to duplicate error since the docker image works for me

Comment: Yes, but it is always listening to 8050. I don't know the right way to change the port. I edited my post so hope it can help you

Comment: its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working now. in my case, it is not working with localhost because maybe I have also installed the apache server. but when I use docker default machine IP with port 8050 then it is working